# add trailing 0's to a string in a df.Column dependent on length

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for a sort of chain method to apply to a df.

consider the following DF.

```
Store
1
33
455
```

what I'm trying to do is ascertain the length and append a 0 based on the length.

I've tried a simple for loop which i thought may work

```
for s in df.Store:
  if s.str.len() == 3:
    "0" + s
```

however this doesn't work.

I've also tried slicing the DF and each variable one by one

```
if df.Store == df[df['Store'].str.len() == 1]:
    "0" + df.Store
```

but neither work and just return a blank output.

I'm working with an object dtype.

desired output:

```
Store
0001
0033
0455
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
df['Store'] = df['Store'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html).

If want append `0` values by maximum length of string is possible count length by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with `max`:

```
df['Store'] = df['Store'].astype(str)
df['Store'] = df['Store'].str.zfill(df['Store'].str.len().max())
print (df)
  Store
0   001
1   033
2   455
```

If want append `0` by scalar :

```
df['Store'] = df['Store'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
print (df)
  Store
0  0001
1  0033
2  0455
```